# Extracting text between delimiters in SQL

Tags: sql

How do I extract all the value from a column separated by commas into a separate table? There could be up to 14 different values in the column.

Example:

```
2,8,5,10,12
```

Comment: SQL probably isn't the best tool for this type of data scrubbing.  Do you have anything else at your disposal, maybe Java or Perl?

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated values. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Unfortunately not, only have SQL. These values are used as foreign key into another table so I need to split the values. Thanks

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Some products have functionality that can be useful here.

Comment: Storing table references as comma separated strings is really a very bad idea. You should consider redesigning your table structures.

Comment: I agree with jarlh... Oracle has REGEX functions and with PLSQL you can tokenize a string.

Comment: For Postgres: `select * from unnest(string_to_array('2,8,5,10,12', ','))`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2016, then you may be in luck. You can use the [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx) function.

Otherwise, it cannot be done easily.

Comment: No I'm not using SQL Server 2016 :(!

Comment: @Natalie: so which DBMS **are** you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012